# How to access tile from 2d tile palette by code by name of prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to select the tile from tile palette by name of the tile\prefab progmatically.

i tried to access the tile  from name of the prefab do i have to type cast the prefab to tile from gameobject.

```
        Tile returnPrefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/one.prefab", typeof(GameObject));
```

or

```
GameObject returnPrefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/one.prefab", typeof(GameObject));
```